# Define collation on a per query basis

Tags: apache-cayenne

We're using Apache Cayenne to integrate an already existing MS SQL Server database with our application (I have **no permission** to change the database DDL, including the table/schema/database collation).

The database is using a specific collation (croatian) which defines single characters like "nj" and "dž", so when I do a `LIKE` query:

`select * from table where name like '%N%'`
I get zero results, on the other hand If i do:
`select * from table where name like '%NJ%'`
I get multiple results.

Obviously this is simple to fix by adding `collate` to the end of the query, but I know of no way of doing this with Cayenne. Any way to implement this without dropping the ORM-benefits as a whole?

**tl;dr**: Is there any way to preprocess queries before going to the database, like so:

`query = query + ' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use custom DB adapter with custom SQL translator that will append required part to all select queries. 
Can be implemented like this for Cayenne **4.0**:

```
public class CustomSQLServerAdapter extends SQLServerAdapter {

    public CustomSQLServerAdapter(/* all params */) {
        super(/* all params */);
    }

    @Override
    public SelectTranslator getSelectTranslator(SelectQuery<?> query, EntityResolver entityResolver) {
        return new SQLServerSelectTranslator(query, this, entityResolver) {
            @Override
            protected void doTranslate() {
                super.doTranslate();
                sql += " collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS";
            }
        };
    }
}
```

To use this adapter you can contribute custom detector for it ([see docs](https://cayenne.apache.org/docs/4.0/cayenne-guide/#contributing-to-service-collections)) or set it directly in Modeler (data node -> adapter).